# Picture breaks during download

Tags: node.js, express

When a file is uploaded, the image is breaks down and not displayed. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

> console.log(file._props):

```
{ SYSFILE_ID: 396,
   FILE_CONTENT:
   '����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\...etc.',
   NAME: '1472042903_31.2.jpg',
   COMMENTS: 'null',
   MIMETYPE: 'image/jpeg' }
```

Moreover, only images break, and text files always work.

controller:

```
module.exports.download = function (req, res) {
  SysFiles.findById(req.params.SYSFILE_ID).then(file => {
    var fileContents = Buffer.from(file._props.FILE_CONTENT, "base64");
    var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    readStream.end(fileContents);
    res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + encodeURIComponent(file._props.NAME));
    res.set('Content-Type', file._props.MIMETYPE);
    readStream.pipe(res);
  })
};
```

Result:

> file 1472042903_31.2.jpg

```
1472042903_31.2.jpg: data
```

I upload images/files this way:

```
module.exports.upload = async function (req, res) {
  const sysFileObj = {
    COMMENTS: req.body.COMMENTS,
    NAME: req.file.originalname,
    MIMETYPE: req.file.mimetype,
    FILE_CONTENT: req.file.buffer
  };
  try {
    await SysFiles.create(sysFileObj);
    res.status(201).json(sysFileObj);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler(res, e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're saving the files in your Database (probably as a blob). Which is a very bad idea because of following reasons:

1. Sooner or later, database will be flooded with lots of binary data and will cost you in the long run.
2. Backend server which should be spending its CPU cycles in processing requests will be busy "serving files". The files should always be statically served, i.e., a dedicated file hosting server.

Now coming back to your original query, this is definitely an issue of encoding/decoding text, but at a quick glance looks like issue while you upload the data(save in your db). I have never tried saving files in db in node using sequelize but can suggest you to try the following:

In your download API, try to save the file from your db to your disk. You will notice that the file will not be previewed by any image viewer. Try using different encoding/decoding method  until file becomes previewable.. Long shot but if image preview works, then downloading part will also work

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var fileContents = Buffer.from(file._props.FILE_CONTENT, "base64");
```

seems to assume that `file._props.FILE_CONTENT` is base64-encoded, which is not the case. The existence of `\u0000` in the output is a hint that this is most likely utf-8, so you need:

```
var fileContents = Buffer.from(file._props.FILE_CONTENT, "utf-8");
```

BUT!! The more sane thing to do is not to treat a binary image as a string to begin with, when you load it from a file, you should load it as binary, which IIUC `fs.readFileSync()` does by default for binary files.

Comment: I already did this, it didn’t help me, the error remained the same